# Is there a way to make a function, that once it's been executed it will return in the function that it is in?

Tags: c#

In case of a failed check. I would like to execute a function, that would perform what it's meant to do and then force `return;` in a function that it has been called from. As such:

```
if (somethingImportant >= 0) {
    MyFunction(somethingImportant, __LINE__);
    return;
}
```

However I would happily trade it for one-liner if that's possible. I want it to just execute a function and `return;` whatever function it is in. Simply because it will make my code look cleaner and more readable, as multiple returns throughout the code look ugly.

I tried `throw new Exception()`, which throws an Exception, sometimes however it's not Exception worthy, also, I'm working in Unity game engine, which means that any thrown Exceptions will be listed in Console Log over there, which I'm keen to avoid. There are multiple Assets that start behaving as if the world is ending. As well, I need ability to distinguish between a minor info, a mishap, a warning and an actual Exception, which makes usage of this truly unpleasant as they all look the same. All Exceptions are noted as errors, no wiggle room. You can execute your own function, but it's accompanied by an Exception regardless of what that functionality you add is.

A solution could be a something that works like `throw new Exception()` which doesn't actually inform Unity of an Exception (can you silence the Exception and only interrupt the function? throw without Exception?). Then I could craft a custom Exception which I could fill with my functions and have my solution.

Perfect demonstration of what I would want to achieve is:

```
try
{
    if ("no" != "match") throw new Exception("OMAGAH!");
    Debug.Log("Because of what happened, I will NOT get executed");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.Log("My message is safe here, I get to do whatever I do, no Exceptions truly thown, and the error was: " + e);
}
```

Which results exclusively in following outcome:

```
My message is safe here, I get to do whatever I do, no Exceptions truly thown, and the error was: System.Exception: OMAGAH!
at TestEngine.Start () [0x00004] in
```

Note all the functionality/outcome of it:
1. You can put it in any position, in any block and scope.
2. It prevents further execution of a script that it's in.
3. It silences/prevents the Exception from showing up.
4. It lets me to execute whatever function I want and will never mention the Exception. I can make Debug.LogWarn, Debug.Log, Debug.Error, I'm the master of the Exception.

One problem, try-catch block is much bigger than two liner in the first part of this post. It does exactly what I want it to do, but it's too big.

**TLDR: Is it possible, with single-line piece of code, to execute a function and have it perform its duties, and stop further execution of code (like `Exception` does but without actually throwing `Exception`)?**

Comment: `multiple returns throughout the code look ugly.` Only if your methods are too long. Keep your methods to less than a dozen lines, and this kind of issue doesn't arise. (Sometimes you can't - with big switches and suchlike, but generally longer methods are violating SRP and should be split up into multiple methods)

Comment: _"multiple returns throughout the code look ugly"_ - that's a matter of opinion. Personally I prefer code to "fail fast", rather than have multiple nested "if" statements and one return at then end.

Comment: @stuartd I prefer a single line that - as you put - fails fast, rather than two lines.

Comment: check task cancellation token : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation

Comment: @Eldar interesting, though I don't see how to use a cancellation for this without throwing an `OperationCanceledException`? Is there another way?

Comment: @JohnDoe so you're trying to create your own [jump statement](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-jump-statements-break-continue-goto-return-and-throw/)? The only one from that list that replicates exception behaviour is `goto` (and that's because if you allow a bit of hyperbole, an exception is like a `goto` without a label saying where it's actually going to go). But of course that's not a solution.

Comment: I'm here puzzling with `OperationCanceledException`, turns out it throws error only to function containing the task, which forces me to use try-catch block, which brings me to square one. It doesn't provide apparent solution.

Comment: @stuartd I thought about jump for a long time, but jump doesn't conveniently allow me to block code execution. I'm trying to recreate behaviour Exception, without actually throwing an Exception error to Unity engine. I even provided a working but too big solution.

Comment: Does Unity log caught (handled) exceptions to the console? That seems odd.

Comment: @stuartd It indeed does. The only way I can silence it is by putting the Exception in try-catch, and have some commands in catch, but then it doesn't block the execution. Even if I create a custom Exception, it still catches it and shows it in the console. I have three ways to do it, and in all three ways I find myself smashing against the wall with seemingly impossible obstacle.

Comment: I just realised I could do with exactly this kind of construct in the code I'm working on now - I don't want to throw, but I want to jump out of the current method from a local function.

Comment: No, I really did think "I could really do with one of those now". But I don't think there is one. So I did something else instead.

Comment: @stuartd Would you be willing to share? Or is it something that would work for you, but not for me? _I like the way my previous comment was deleted._

Comment: In the end I refactored the whole thing away. Odd that your comment was deleted - someone must have flagged it, I guess. These things happen..

Comment: @stuartd I guess I'll refactor it too. Sad, seeing the awesome things happening in C#, I expected this to be fairly known/possible. It ironically seems that this one would be easiest to implement under the hood. Do you believe that one could write a .dll file in C++ or any other language necessary in order to create this behaviour as a custom part of C#?

Comment: I don't think so, and is it really worth it? Sometimes you have to go with options that aren't optimal, or that you just dislike - so working with the tools you have, even when you feel they're working aginst you, or preventing you from doing things the way you want to.